# Two git repositories, need to exclude paths in one of them, but keep it in sync

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have two repositories:

internal_development (origin)
external_development (ext)

I need to keep the codebase in sync with them, that means - I have to pull commits from internal to external and vice-versa. But the catch here is, that a very large part of the internal_development is confidential and should not get merged into the external development repository. I know git isn't meant to do that, but there is porbably some way to do this, right?

I tried to do it like this:

- copied manually file structure from origin/master, excluding paths that were confidential. set up new bare repository with the first commit.
- Then in the **internal repository**, added new ext remote and ran: git checkout -b master_ext ext/master
- Then checkout back to internal master, added new "test" file and commited it.
- Checkout in ext/master, tried this command: "git merge --no-commit --no-ff origin/master"
- It merged all of the commits from internal master + new files that were supposed to be confidential.

I could run "git reset" for all the directories that should not get into the external repository, but it wouldn't help me, because the previous commits from internal get pulled inside as well and they could just checkout these commits and see the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that a very large part of the internal_development is confidential and should not get merged into the external development repository.

Then it (the confidential part) should be in its own repo (see [split a Git repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two#Splitarepositoryintwo-UsingGittosplit-outadirectory)). Any other solution (keeping both confidential and non-confidential parts in the same repo) is too risky.

The non-confidential part can stay in the original repo, and the new confidential repo can reference the first repo as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (as do the necessary symlinks to recreate the right tree structure)

Comment: This seems probably the most reasonable way to go about it. Can I convert sub-directories within the project to be git bare repos with relevant history intact?  
And remove commits from this master repository?

Comment: @WraithLux that is what https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two#Splitarepositoryintwo-UsingGittosplit-outadirectory describes.